React Formik to have null as default value if input is cleared
In my ReactJS project, I am using Formik
const formikPaymentForm = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    ezidebitAmount: null, // or undefined
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object({
    ezidebitAmount: Yup.number().nullable(),
  }),

and in render
<TextField
            name="ezidebitAmount"
            label="Ezidebit Amount"
            type="number"
            autoComplete="off"
            error={Boolean(touched.ezidebitAmount && errors.ezidebitAmount)}
            helperText={touched.ezidebitAmount && errors.ezidebitAmount}
            onChange={formikPaymentForm.handleChange}
            value={formikPaymentForm.values.ezidebitAmount}
            fullWidth
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          />

and if I clear the input by deleting from keyboard then onSubmit it gives me the empty string which is not right as I have mentioned it number field.
Can we somehow set it to null if I have cleared the value and type is number?
I tried this:
onChange={(event) => {
              const value = event.target.value;
              formikPaymentForm.setFieldValue(
                'ezidebitAmount',
                value === '' ? null : Number(value) // Transform empty string to undefined
              );
            }}

which is working fine, but I have so many forms in my application and I need a central solution for this

If I were you, I'd like to create wrapper component if it doesn't exist in the docs:
const CustomTextField = (props: Props, form: <Not Sure what is Formik type>) => {

  return (
    <TextField
            {...props}
            onChange={(event) => {
              const value = event.target.value;
              if (props.type === 'number'){
                form.setFieldValue(
                  props.name,
                  value === '' ? null : Number(value) // Transform empty string to undefined
                );
              } else {
                form.setFieldValue(props.name, value);
              }
            }}
          />
  )
}

Then use something like:
<CustomTextField
            name="ezidebitAmount"
            label="Ezidebit Amount"
            type="number"
            autoComplete="off"
            error={Boolean(touched.ezidebitAmount && errors.ezidebitAmount)}
            helperText={touched.ezidebitAmount && errors.ezidebitAmount}
            form={formikPaymentForm}
            value={formikPaymentForm.values.ezidebitAmount}
            fullWidth
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          />

Yes, you need to replace, but it'll centralize everything
